# How to get rid of the indices of qubits at the side of a custom gate when visualizing a circuit (IBM Qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, hadamard

I have written a function that applies the Hadamard gate to all qubits in a circuit, and use the `draw()` function to visualize the circuit. However, there is this column of indices of the qubits that appears with the custom gate [here is a picture of the `draw()` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4tcv.jpg). How do I get rid of this?

[picture of the function superpose_all that applies the Hadamard gate to all qubits in a circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z7Cy.jpg)

Comment: The problem is that your function return a sub circuit which is in main circuit drawn as a block. To show individual Hadamarda, do not use function and put them on qubits directly in the main circuit.

Comment: I don't think that is currently supported. If you would like to make a case for that use-case, request it as a feature in https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/new?type%3A+feature+request